# Не работает беспроводная клавиатура от Logitech

Tags: клавиатура

Я не пользовался клавой примерно 3 месяца, за это время она естественно разрядилась, я поставил ее на зарядку огоньки сразу загорелись я писал с клавиатуры когда она была на зарядке все работало, но вот она подзарядилась 2 часа и как только я ее снимаю с зарядки она моментально отключается и вообще никак не работает, ложу обратно и она снова работает все кнопки все ок. Что делать не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Глубокая разрядка аккумуляторов - три варианта:

1. Сделать несколько циклов - заряд-разряд, для возможного восстановления, может, частичного, возможности аккумуляторов воспринимать заряд
2. Поменять аккумуляторы
3. Работать на зарядке